# Can we use non primary key column as shard key in memsql

Tags: singlestore

I am using join on some column which are not part of primary key. so for these column i need to store data with same value in same node. so join will work locally.

Answer (score 0):

The shard key may be a subset of the primary key, but MemSQL does not support using a shard key with columns which aren't in the primary key. This is because it would be harder to efficiently maintain the uniqueness of the primary key if the same primary key value can be sharded on different partitions. See http://docs.memsql.com/latest/concepts/distributed_sql/ for more information.